# How to identify if it is a pink guava or white guava from plant or leaf

Tags: identification, leaves, planting, guavas, stems

I wanted to plant pink guava because pink guava is rare in my area. It is a small town. White guava is very common here. So, I went to a small nursery here. He sold me a plant of about 5 feet and said it is pink guava. In fact, he said all guavas he has are pink guavas. I don't trust him and can't wait for a year to confirm the right one. I only have space to plant one tree only. I bought it anyway.

Is there any way to identify from the leaves or the stem or the plant itself if it is pink guava or a white one?

A few pictures of the plant are given below. Sorry for the bad quality pictures.

[image: guava plant]

[image: guava leaf]

Comment: when you say pink guava, are you referring to the skin of the fruit, or the interior of  the fruits?

Comment: interior of the fruit @Bamboo  something like this https://5.imimg.com/data5/KJ/YM/MY-30273368/pink-guava-500x500.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Psidium guajava* seems to be the  one you have - unfortunately, there are no indicators in the foliage or stems as to what colour the inside of the fruits will be, could be white, yellow or pink. This link https://www.britannica.com/plant/common-guava might be of interest, from which you will see there is another variety of guava that has smaller, rounded fruits which are dark pink in colour on the outside, which is why I queried 'pink' guava.

Answer (score 0):

The leaf of red or pink guava is uneven at the end. But in white guava which is common guava has round shape leaf.(One end of the leaf is slightly out)

Comment: Welcome to Gardening and Landscaping.  You could improve your answer by posting some pictures or linking to a website.